# How do I style a span to look like a link without using javascript?

Tags: html, css

For my website I will need to use `<span>` instead of `<a>`, because I am using mostly ajax and thus instead of links I have onclick ajax events as attributes in my spans.

As a result, I had to manually style the spans to look like links. I have used hover and visited pseudo classes to change background and text colour, but to change the mouse default to a pointer finger on hover, will I need to use javascript? Or can I do that using css?

Also, I have just realized: I could not just use the `<a>` tag anyways instead of `<span>`, but just instead of an href, I would include an onclick? It should work just the same, no?

Comment: If you leave out all anchors and use `span` instead you are penalizing yourself on search engines since spiders don't know what to crawl anymore without href.

Comment: @user1787489 can you please clarify what's the advantage of using <span> over <a> in terms of ajax?  i'm confused about "onclick ajax events as attributes".  thank you so much :)

Answer (score 144):

```css
span {
     cursor:pointer;
     color:blue;
     text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hyperlink</a><br />
<span>Span</span>
```

Additionally, you can use `:hover` pseudo-class to style the element when hovered (you can use any styles not just the ones originally used). For example:

```css
span:hover {
     text-decoration:none;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Note that if your website is public and you are counting on search engines to crawl your site, you lose a lot by leaving out links without `href` since spiders have nothing to grab on while crawling your page.

You should use a complete link - in case your javascript breaks down the user is still able to navigate through pages:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>
```

than you can disable the link with jquery by using [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) - and you totally separated base html and the javascript part, meaning your site is still usable without javascript on.

Than you don't need to bother with span hover and anything - but just for the sake of it

```
span:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

will enable hover hand cursor on hovered span.

Comment: bare in mind that preventDefault() can have unreliable effects in different browsers.  It has only been a recent change that IE would even allow you to prevent certain events.  While the browsers are becoming more and more standardized overriding default browser behavior should be done carefully and requires a large amount of cross browser testing.

Comment: @Ivoelk show me exact sample when preventDefault() does not work. Also you are replying to a 4 years old answer.

Comment: `:hover` is redundant, `cursor` means "Change the mouse cursor when pointing at this element" and `:hover` means "when pointing at this element" so you're saying "Change the mouse cursor when you are pointing at this element and when you are pointing at this element".

Answer (score 9):

## Option1

Just use an `anchor` link as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunction();"> Link </a>
```

## Option2

I don't know why you would wanna use span , but if you do you can do the following styles to make it look similar to an anchor link.

```
span {
    color: #000000; /* Change this with links color*/
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

span:hover {
    color: #444444; /* Change the value to with anchors hover color*/
}
```

Comment: if you have a Single Page App the # will mess with everything, changing the URL when you are not trying to is not always a good idea

Answer (score 7):

Just add `cursor:pointer;` in your `span` css.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS to display the cursor as a pointer:

```
<span style="cursor: pointer;">Pseudolink</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kkepg/

Answer (score 2):

You could use an anchor. But within javascript you'd have to use `event.preventDefault()` But there is a CSS method thats smaller and easier. Keep your span and use this:

```
span:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: @StefanNeubert What if he also wanted to add particular properties to the element on `hover` as well as changing the cursor?

Comment: Then of course you need it. But you should always keep your code light and omit unnecessary pseudo-attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cursor to a pointer by specifying the `cursor: pointer` CSS rule.

You can also use `<a>` tags instead of `<span>`, in fact they can behave nicer with screen readers and other similar devices. You don't need to leave out the `href` attribute if you use the `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` JavaScript functions in the `onClick` handler. This way you can retain some level of backward compatibility with non-JS enabled browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a button instead of span and use bootstrap css classes to style it like a link:

`<button class="btn btn-link">Link</button>`

It will react on mouseOver as normal links do.
Run the code snippet to preview the result:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-link">this is my link styled with bootstrap</button>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. It is written how to make a span looks like a link

Answer (score -2):

You can use an onClick event but if I remember correctly, you must return false in order to prevent your page from jumping around; something like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="myfunction();return false;">
```

or: `<a href="#" onClick="return myfunction();">` provided that `myfunction` will return false.

You can also directly call a javascript from href but you must cast the result to void in order to block to the browser to try to follow the result as a valid link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(myFunction())">
```

Even if you still want to use the onClick property; it would still be a good idea to replace the `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0)" ...>`.

Other people have mentionned using the `event.preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`.  I don't remember ever using one of these but I must admit that it has been many years since the last time that I have coding some javascript in a HTML link; so you should definitely investigate the use of these two functions.

EDIT: maybe that using a `href="javascript:void(0)"` could be a bad idea sometimes; see http://drupal.org/node/1193068 .