# How can I execute each switch statement case in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  tags like this:

```
<a id="profile1">...</a>
<a id="profile2">...</a>
...
<a id="profile6">...</a>
```

and a switch statement:

```
switch () {
 case 1:
   $('#contactName').prepend(contacts[0].name);
   $('#contactPicture').attr('src', contacts[0].picture);
  break;
 case 2:
   $('#contactName').prepend(contacts[1].name);
   $('#contactPicture').attr('src', contacts[1].picture);
  break;
  ...
 case 6:
   $('#contactName').prepend(contacts[5].name);
   $('#contactPicture').attr('src', contacts[5].picture);
  break;
};
```

If I click on each 'a tag' I want to execute each switch statement's case. How can I do that in JS? (I tried .on() but I did sg wrong)
Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: Do you mean that when you click on #profile2 you execute all 6 cases? (if so you don't need a switch).

Comment: All your cases do pretty much the same thing?

Comment: If you want to execute every one why use a switch? If you don't want to execute every one, when? Show us more context.

Comment: You can manage execution of cases by removing or adding `break;` statement.

Comment: `switch ()` but switch what? I guess your code just need some refactorization without any `switch` statement..

Comment: Sorry I mean If I click on profile1 I want case1, profile2 -> case2, profile6 -> case6, you got the idea. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an ***expression*** for `switch` to evaluate?  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: This is not the way to accomplish this at all. First, you shouldn't use `a` elements just as a hook for a `click` event. Use `a` for navigation. If you need a `click` hook, just a `span` instead. Next, all of the elements can be combined into an array and then you can just use the index of the clicked element in the array with the two instructions you want executed.

Answer (score 2):

No switch needed:

```
<a class="profile">...</a>
```

and

```
$(".profile").on("click",function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
  var idx = $(this).index(); // assuming links in a container   
  $('#contactName').prepend(contacts[idx].name);
  $('#contactPicture').attr('src', contacts[idx].picture);
});
```

Please note the following:

[How do i style a span to look like a link without using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070086/how-do-i-style-a-span-to-look-like-a-link-without-using-javascript)